# swagger/index.html shows a blank page (asp.net core)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

I am writing a web api in ASP.NET CORE for the data models **Package** and **Content**. They are originally from MSSQL so I connected to the db server successfully. After writing http requests in the controllers, when I ran the project to test, it takes me to **swagger/index.html** that shows a blank page, I have no idea why.

[image]
Here is my **program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

//OperationsContext is a db context that has both content and package dbcontext
builder.Services.AddDbContext<OperationsContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
/*builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();*/

builder.Services.AddScoped<IContentRepository, ContentRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPackageRepository, PackageRepository>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseSwagger();

app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment() || app.Environment.IsProduction())
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/Package/swagger.json", "Package v1");
    }
    else
    {
        // To deploy on IIS
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/Package/swagger.json", "Package v1");
    }

});
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();    
app.MapControllers(); 
app.Run();
```

I am assuming it's the program.cs, but there are no issues when I ran it. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swagger UI [does not support](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#browser-support) Internet Explorer. Use Chrome, Firefox, Safari, or Edge instead.

Comment: Missing/incorrect configs, most likely. Does your code contain the string `VOMPackage`?

Comment: yes it does. I mistyped it on the comment but everything is correct.